# Equivalence of two definitions of rational equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a variety. In order to define the Chow ring of $X$, there seem to be two different ways of defining rational equivalence of $i$-cycles $Z \sim Z'$.

Definition 1:
$Z \sim Z'$ iff there is a subvariety $V \subseteq X$ of dimension $i+1$ and a rational function $\varphi \in K(V)$ such that $Z - Z' = \text{div}(\varphi)$. This is the definition at the Wikipedia article for [adequate equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequate_equivalence_relation#Examples_of_equivalence_relations), for example.

Definition 2:
$Z \sim Z'$ iff there is a subvariety $V \subseteq \mathbb{P}^1 \times X$ and points $a,b \in \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $(V \cap \{a\} \times X) - (V \cap \{b\} \times X) = Z - Z'$. I've seen this stated both with and without the additional hypothesis that $V$ is flat over $\mathbb{P}^1$. This is the definition at the Wikipedia page for [Chow Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_ring), for example.

Of course, I'd love to see a proof in as much generality as possible, but I will be satisfied with a proof in the case when $X$ is a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $Z,Z'$ Cartier divisors on $X$.

**EDIT** I should add my attempts: it's not hard to see that the first definition implies the second, by taking $V$ equal to the graph of the rational function on the dimension $i + 1$ subvariety and taking the pushforward.

For the second direction, we need to show  (in the case of divisors) that $V$ somehow is related to the graph of a non-constant rational function on $X$. But I don't see why this must be true: surely there are examples where $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \{x\}$ for some $x \in X$ is not just a point! (A dumb example is $\mathbb{P}^1 \times W$ for some subvariety $W$ - this only shows that $W$ is rationally equivalent to $W$)

Comment: I think the equivalence is explained in Section 1.5 of Fulton.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can get access to Fulton, but at least for others who find this question later, a free reference or proof sketch would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They aren't equivalent in general (the first definition is incorrect). See the answer to this [post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11774/difference-between-equivalence-relations-on-algebraic-cycles?rq=1) on MO.

Comment: Also, I think in general one wants to define rational equivalence to be *generated* by the relations you're giving. I don't know of a free reference — Eisenbud and Harris send you over to Fulton and IIRC for Fulton's proof you need to have set up the pushforward and that takes some work.

Comment: @BrandonCarter I'm not sure what part of the MO post is relevant - the accepted answer corrects an old Wikipedia definition of the second statement (for the case of algebraic rather than rational equivalence) but the correct form is the one I have here.

Comment: @Hoot do you know if this is necessary for the rational function definition? I know it is unnecessary in the case of divisors (since we can multiply rational functions together) which leads me to believe something similar is true for the general case. I don't have much intuition for the second definition, so it very well may be required.